# convert values in columns into numbers python int error

Tags: python-3.x, data-conversion

I have the following code and when I run it there is a problem : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable .How can i solve it please?

```
def str2number(amount):
if amount[-1] == 'M':
    return float(amount[1:-1])*1000000
elif amount[-1] == 'K':
    return float(amount[1:-1])*1000
else:
    return float(amount[1:])
```

data['ValueNum'] = data['Value'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))
data['WageNum'] = data['Wage'].apply(lambda x: str2number(x))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1cRp.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZwdc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure your datatype is str in your lambda function. Also, in your str2number function your indexes are incorrect. amount[1:-1] for '10M' would return 0 with how you had it.

```
def str2number(amount: str) -> float:
  if str(amount[-1]).upper() == 'M':
      return float(amount[:-1])*1000000
  elif str(amount[-1]).upper() == 'K':
      return float(amount[:-1])*1000
  else:
      return float(amount)
    
print(str2number('10M'))
```

Output:

```
10000000.0
```

Change your lambda to take a string

```
data['ValueNum'] = data['Value'].apply(lambda x: str2number(str(x))) data['WageNum'] = data['Wage'].apply(lambda x: str2number(str(x)))
```